# Video players that have frame by frame playback feature

Tags: media-player

What video players out there exists that have frame by frame playback feature ?

Comment: `"We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise..."` The answers to this question are, in fact, straightforward facts: either a software has this feature or it does not. It's black and white. How exactly will this question lead to arguments or debates?

Comment: As an author of the post, I must say, I cannot understand why this was closed as non-constructive. It is a simple, straightforward question - as StormRyder says, a player either has this feature or it does not. Please, can somebody elaborate?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**[SMPlayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/)** can do that.

Pause the movie

from the menu choose Play > **Frame step** or press <kbd>.</kbd> (dot)

SMPlayer is free and open source. a portable version is also [available](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/downloads.php).

Comment: It's lame that it allows only frame step "forward" and not back.

Comment: That feature is available in the "base" mplayer, too. But it sucks. I'd suggest to use a NLE program like virtualdub or kdenlive.

Comment: You can step backwards according to [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/smplayer/feature-requests/524/) feature request. Not a clue how, have asked on the thread though.

Comment: How do you even know it's stepping forward?  I have tried clicking pause and pushing DOT 100 times and the time still shows the same number of seconds Similarly clicking play..frame step

Comment: SMPlayer can do forward and BACKWARD. Ensure that under Option -> Settings the option mpv is selected under Multimediamodule. Than use "." (dot) for Step Frame Forward and use "," (comma) for Step Backward.

Answer (score 11):

Media Player Classic (Home Cinema)
[Sourceforge](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: To access that function, all you need to do is pause the video and press the left and right arrow to go back and forth by one frame.

Comment: @alex not working for me http://superuser.com/questions/1133127/how-can-i-go-forward-and-back-frame-by-frame-in-media-player-classic-left-and

Comment: try `CTRL + LEFT`

Comment: no longer under development. (and besides when I tried it recently I ran into a bug of not going back frames though that bug might be just my situation)

Answer (score 11):

I've landed on this page quite often when trying to watch video clips frame by frame. Having tried many of the suggestions, I'm still frustrated with the lack of availability or ease of use of such a feature, which I find indispensable in an analytic environment (I'm not trying to go frame by frame on Leia's slave costume).

Today having tried VLC only to discover it has a frame by frame *forward* but not *backward*, and subsequently landed on the VLC forums where many users ask for the feature, I learned something. It is apparently not an easy thing to do for certain codecs (as far as I can tell, the ones designed for streaming, or "multi-frame" compressions). For example, ImageJ will save AVI files which are evidently a sequence of JPEG images more or less concatenated into a single file. So here frame by frame is easy---the "codec" is "frame based". Take an MPEG movie, where if, on frame 512, the top left corner has not changed since frame 265, video players are unable to go backwards and render the image correctly for frame 511 without theoretically loading some unknown number of previous frames to build a "history" of the image.

Needless to say I do not believe any manipulation of data is impossible with a computer and certainly if these video players can render to the screen they could keep a buffer in RAM with a history of rendered frames to at least allow some amount of frame by frame, but this is not feasible for an entire HD movie and thus, at least in VLC's case, they don't see the point of implementing it for clips of some maximum duration.

Comment: [There's a plugin for that](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11585)!

Comment: I guess even if that plugin for VLC to go back frames works, it would be keyframes, which is fine for many though darda might want actual frames

Comment: @LouisMaddox that plugin looks very limited, a comment mentions that it doesn't have a key to go back a frame.. So VLC still has "E" to go forward frames and no key to go back frames

Answer (score 4):

[Quick time](http://osxdaily.com/2009/08/23/15-useful-keyboard-shortcuts-for-quicktime/) can do it.

> Hold down <kbd>K</kbd> and tap <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd> – allows you to scrub the video in slow motion, viewing in either rewind or forward frame by frame

Comment: Or pause with space bar and use left-right arrow keys. But of course, QT is Mac/Windows only. The question doesn't specify the OS, but if it is for Linux there seems to be no player with the ability to go back frame by frame. I have to use a WinXP VM with QT for that.

Comment: Looks like QT isn't supported on windows anymore

Answer (score 1):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/index).

Comment: VirtualDub isn't a media player. ¬_¬

Answer (score 1):

**[The KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/forums/)** will do this.

<kbd>Space</kbd> to pause and then <kbd>f</kbd> to advance frame (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to step back).

[Review of KMP](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-media-player-replacement.htm).

Comment: not clear where to download that now?  your KMPlayer link to forums doesn't work.  This looks maybe ok http://www.kmplayer.com/ but when clicking PC 64X, it goes to some funny site (naver.com?!), and it's all in chinese

Comment: This works nicely! Step back default seems to be ALT+F now.

Answer (score 0):

mplayer will can do this. You can press `.` to go to the next frame

Answer (score 0):

I use [Zoom Player](http://www.inmatrix.com/files/zoomplayer_download.shtml). Control frame-by-frame playback using the mouse scroll wheel. both ways.

Comment: Downloaded 2012-08-08. I found the mouse wheel zooms by default. The frame-by-frame seems unreliable for an AVI created in MATLAB; the player acknowledges "next frame" and "previous frame" but the image does not always change. Perhaps compression really trips up these players which are aiming for a huge feature set.

Answer (score 0):

ImageJ can load some videos as a stack which makes frame-by-frame easy in either direction.
http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/

It's significantly limited as far as codecs.