# How can I go forward and back frame by frame in media player classic? (left and right are jumping many seconds!)

Tags: media-player-classic

I like media player classic because it has built in support for showing milliseconds.

I would like to be able to move frame by frame

I have heard that left and right should move frame by frame, but it's clearly not, it's jumping many seconds

It's MPC version  1.7.10 64bit

Here's a sample mp3 though  11 seconds

[enter link description here](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/f9c63992722523f0541305c649d369e320161009221818/ed2464da35f038c45acfff9bdd9e00f820161009221818/c6544f)

If I pause it at 0:00.000 and I push the right arrow then it jumps to 0:05.000 so it jumps 5 seconds!

[image]

Comment: not an answer but quicktime lets you go frame by frame, though doesn't support milliseconds.  Doesn't show frame number either but I notice that for that mp3 file I Get about 4 taps of right per second.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to press

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (left arrow) to jump by just one frame backwards,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to jump forward.

Comment: also I recommend when doing that that you also right click the time and do high precision otherwise you won't see the time change within seconds.

Comment: I tried this with a 240fps video from my iPhone (with the High Precision timer on) and compared MPC's frame-stepping to VLC's frame-by-frame mode, and MPC definitely skipped frames that VLC didn't (MPC took 10 `ctrl+right-arrow` keypresses to advance, whereas VLC took 17 keypresses. MPC's high-precision timer showed it sometimes jumped multiple frames between presses too - that's weird).

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was about Media Player Classic, but since it stopped development, thought it was worthwhile to point to [Media Player Classic - Black Edition](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpcbe/) which is currently being developed. Just tried it, and it also supports <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to frame-step back and forwards.

Edit: There used to be an option to show frames in the playback time, but that appears to be gone. Now instead, if you right-click on the time in the lower-right, a context menu shows a checkbox to display milliseconds.

Comment: It also works on Media Player Classic Home Cinema (non Black Edition)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on `Turn fast seek off` within the options menu.

[image]

Comment: -1 No that has absolutely nothing to do with it at all.  Fastseek has no influence on ctrl+arrow.  To move in fine adjustments you use ctrl+arrow and that works regardless of whether fastseek is on or off. (and btw, Arrow alone won't move frame by frame in MPC)